# Hide back button

Tags: swift, xcode8

I'm working on my 1st real game. I have 2 view controllers. The 1st one has an animated picture, and the player can enter there names. The 2nd one is displaying the game. After the game is over the player can play again or reset. The reset takes them back to the 1st VC so they can give new names.  My question is how do I hide the reset until I need it.  To put it there I made a button and command dragged it to the 1st VC and selected show.

Thanks for any information you might be able to give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using iOS predefined back button then try like this:-

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

or if you have just dragged and drop the `UIBarbutton` then create the `outlet` and hide/show it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an outlet variable to your reset button, you can change the `isHidden` property of it to `true` or `false` appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. That was easy. I needed a little nudge.